# Power series interval of convergence proof

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am given the following power series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(x-a)^n$$

I need to prove that the interval of convergence has a center $a$.

Any tips on how I could prove this?

Comment: The standard approach is to first prove and then use the following lemma: (i) if this power series converges at $x=d$, then it converges for all $x$ satisfying $|x-a|<|d-a|$; (ii) if this power series diverges at $x=d$, then it diverges for all $x$ satisfying $|x-a|>|d-a|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, the series converges at $x=a$. Now assume the series converges at $x = x_0 \ne a$. We get that $a_n(x_0-a)^n \to 0 $. From here we can say that the series is bounded, that is, 
$$\exists M\in\mathbb{R} : |a_n||x_0-a|^n = |a_n(x_0-a)^n| < M $$

Now, let $x$ such that $|x-a|<|x_0-a|$ ($x$ is not further from $a$ than $x_0$). We have
$$ |a_n||x-a|^n < |a_n||x_0-a|^n < M \tag1$$
Now
$$\begin{align} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n(x-a)^n| &< \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n||x_0-a|^n \left|\frac{x-a}{x_0-a}\right|^n  \\ &< M\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{x-a}{x_0-a}\right|^n < \infty
\end{align}$$
When the latter converges as a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) ($\left|\frac{x-a}{x_0-a}\right| < 1$, by $(1)$). Thus, by the [comparion test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(x-a)^n$ converges absolutely (and thus converges).

This shows that the interval of convergence has center $a$. Perhaps you would also be interested in the term [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence).

Comment: The claim you're making is not necessarily true: it may fail when $r$ is the radius of convergence, because a power series may be convergent at one endpoint of the interval of convergence and divergent at the other endpoint.

Comment: @zipirovich You are right. I have edited my post to be precise and more complete.